# UITableView Footer and Header Background color darker than specified

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm Trying to style a TableviewController, and I wish to set the background to a very light gray and the cells to white, with thick borders of the same gray shade. However, after I set background and header colors, they both turn to be a very dark shade (the color code is ok, and the footer is darker than the header).

This is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
```

and to set the header color:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection: Int) {
    if let headerTitle = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerTitle.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        headerTitle.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it for header:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

and it for footer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

}

and remove this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection: Int) {
    if let headerTitle = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerTitle.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        headerTitle.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = gainsBoro
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot to better my code, but it didn't actually solve the problem... However, I noticed two things, the color I was using had alpha to 0.4, and if I set the backgrounds to clear, I see a Black background!, that's why the gray get's darker, so setting alpha to 1 "fixed" it... I put it un quotes because I'm not sure why the background is black, and because changing alpha messes the color... Any Idea why this is?

Comment: @Danf I can not see all code, so I can't give the answer to your question and I don't understand your problem, you set alpha 0.4, and your table becomes black?

Comment: No, with alpha to 0.4 the background is dark gray, as in the screenshot above. If I set the background to clear, it becomes black, as if there was another black layer behind the tableview background, if the alpha is low, the selected color "mixes" with the black background. So to solve the problem I just use alpha to 1, thus completely hiding the black color and the light gray doesn't get mixed.

Comment: The thing is, it would be nice to know where is the black background coming from...

Comment: @Danf Why do you use .clear code? If you use .clear color your UIView shows black color because you delete color.

Comment: @Danf If you add a new storyboard and set .clear code for UIView and show it, you'll see black color, because you delete the color from UIView. I generally use default color, that I see color, which is located under the element which I set default color.

Comment: Do we understand each other, @Danf? I understand some English.

Comment: Yeah, I think we do, but I only tried with .clear to see what was happening. But if I understand correctly, any color I set as background with alpha lower than 1, will let some of the black color pass, thus becoming darker... is that right?

Comment: @Danf Yes. that is right. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621945-clear

Comment: I figured... It's a shame though, since alpha gave a nice touch to the color! Thanks!

Comment: @Danf It's okay. I believe one day you will become one of the best soft engineers because only real software engineer makes mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` views with Xib files, and I'm registering them when the `viewDidLoad` is called:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FooterView", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "FooterView")
```

In the `viewForFooterInSection` function, when the view is dequeued, you only have to set the `tintColor` to the color that you want:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 1 {
        if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "FooterView") as? FooterView {               
            view.tintColor = .red
            return view
        }
    }

    return UIView()
}
```

You can do the same with the Header views but in the `viewForHeaderInSection` function. I guess it will work without registering the views.

This is what my table view looks like for this example.  The blue one is a header view, and the red one is a footer view.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to give the alpha value to the header and footer view.

```
footerView.alpha = 0.3;
headerTitle.alpha = 0.3;
```