# set background color of footerView UI TableView doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview

I use UIView() for remove separate line and it works but changing background color of footer view doesn't work. This is my code. Can somebody explain why? Thank you so much!

```
    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F7F9FC")
    myTableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Comment: Its because frame of footerView is zero.

Comment: use `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F7F9FC")`

Comment: I think you want to change background colour of tableview?

Comment: This is already have been answered
check the link
[BG Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995128/uitableview-footer-and-header-background-color-darker-than-specified/50995285)

Comment: you're right! @Vikky, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must set a frame for footer view. If you just only create UIView then the default of Apple will create UIView with frame is zero. You need to set width, height, x, y for it to display in TableView

```
 let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourWidthExpect, height: yourHeightExpect))
 let footerView =  UIView(frame: frame)
```

After that you can set background color and do anything.

Comment: No worry my friend. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is because the size of your footerView is zero.

```
let footerView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40.0))
footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F7F9FC")
myTableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```