# How to set header or footer background color in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

**Forward:** I had this question and didn't find much on SO about it except a bit of related information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995128/uitableview-footer-and-header-background-color-darker-than-specified), but I eventually figured it out, and thought there ought to be a clearer question and solution posted on SO for others to find, so I'm asking it here and then responding to my own post with what worked great for me (although someone is always welcome to critique).

**Question:** How can I change the background color for headers or footers in a UITableView?

Answer (score 4):

The code below is for changing the background color of the footer. For the header, it's the same, but should be posted in the `willDisplayHeaderView` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let footer = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        footer.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

*Note: I originally thought setting `footer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` would work, but it did not for me. I suspect it was because the `contentView` was covering it up, and this would have to be set to `clear` first, before the `backgroundView` showed. Therefore, I figured it was easiest just to set the color of the content view directly.*

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop in your storyboard UIView for header/footer view.

After that you can edit as you wish in the attribute inspector.

Also you can manipulate with UITableView's delegate functions for header/footer view.